Home with all electric AC & Heat Pump. Want to set up with 2 thermostats -- one of first floor for winter and one on 2nd floor for AC
At the moment we only have a thermostat for both AC & Heat on the top floor and it is fine for the AC but VERY hard to regulate the heat so the bottom floor is warm. When we had gas/radiator heat, the thermostat for the heat was on the bottom floor and that worked fine. We are going to set up two thermostat locations in tandem with the wiring going from the upstairs to the downstairs and just moving the thermostat when the season changes.  However, if we could put two thermostats on a switch so a flip would move the system from one to the other (and not have to move the actual thermostat each time), that would be preferable.  I'm not sure it's possible though. Any thought or experience would be appreciated.  Rachel

Is this a mini split system, or a central forced-air system, or something else? The answer may depend on what technology you are dealing with. However, in my experience with the mini split, this is a known problem and your options are either to block air flow up and down the stairwell somehow or to kludge up some form of "return duct" to recirculate hot air down to the ground level. Or both. This is one of the few things that I have to admit my old hydronic / gas system handled better, largely because it had a radiator at the base of the stairs to create a separate air circulation cell.

It would be best if you sketched what you are proposing. A freehand drawing is fine.

I'd think the easiest solution to seasonally switching your thermostats at two locations would be to put a single pole double throw switch on the C wire.  (Obvs depends on the thermostats and how they're hooked up.)
